# Can't get Curl working in Linux

Tags: php, curl

I can't get curl working in Arch Linux with `php7`, i'm getting the following message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()`

I have the `curl` package installed and `php` package updated, the `curl.so` is present at `/usr/lib/php/modules`.

In my `php.ini`:

```
...
extension=curl.so
...
```

output of `php -m`:

```
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check extensions path:

```
# php -r "phpinfo();"|grep extension
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

Maybe `curl.so` must be located in another path (i.e. `/usr/lib64/php/modules`).

Also you need to check if `curl` library `libcurl` exists.

Comment: `php-config --extension-dir` shows me `/usr/lib/php/modules`

Comment: Have you installed `php` from packages or build it from source?

Comment: installed from official repository, with `pacman -S php`

Comment: I've just updated answer about `libcurl`.

Comment: Sorry If my suggestions is not worked in Arch. I try to help you from Centos 7. After removing `libcurl` package, my `php -m` doesn't show me `curl` module. So, I assume that you not have `libcurl`.

Comment: there is no `libcurl` in Arch repository, isn't it supose to come along with `curl` package?

Comment: You are right. I check https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/curl/files/ and `libcurl` is part of `curl` package. So, the last point is to check `configure` options for builded package. I've seen this following https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/php. All build options is correct (line 132). Sorry, but I don't know how to suggest you. It seems all variants is examined.